# ElasticSearch searching on List<Guid> using Nest C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I used to have type *Person* with field *Guid MetroStation*, and I was searching in elastic:

```
.Query(q => q.Term(tr => tr.Field(fl => fl.MetroStation).Value(MyMetroStation))
```

Now am changing `Guid` to `List<Guid>`. How can I search in elastic for this?

Comment: I want to serch by List<Guid> in Value

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to change your search in any way if you are looking to find `Person` documents where the `MetroStation` Guids **contain** the Guid in the query.

If you're looking for `Person` documents where the `MetroStation` Guids contain **exactly** what is in the query, then you might [consider also indexing the number of Guids in the collection to also query on](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html#_equals_exactly). You can achieve this without indexing the count by using a script query, but if you're looking for performance, then indexing the count will likely perform better (measure it for your use case).

Comment: I want to serch by List<Guid> in Value

Comment: I need somethink like this, but in Nest:
`$params['index'] = 'pokemon';
$params['type']  = 'pokemon_trainer';
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must']['terms']['age'] = array(10, 15);`

Comment: Take a look at the Terms Query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-query-usage.html